# in which cases "as" followed by article?

Tags: grammar

for instance, is it correct to write : "to approve his appointment as chairman of the board and as CEO of the company"? 
Or should it be writenn that way:"to approve his appointment as a chairman of the board and as a CEO of the company"?

Comment: No. "A CEO" or "a chairman" would imply there is more than one.

Comment: I disagree with the previous statement. Although it's not as common, there's nothing wrong with using *a*. And it certainly doesn't mean that there's more than one *currently*. (Although it might imply *one in **a series of** CEOs*, where others existed in the past and might exist in the future.)